# Flatten and reconstruct JSON Snowflake

Tags: sql, arrays, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, querying

I am still learning Snowflake, any help would be really appreciated.

I have a column, let's call it 'result'.

```
{
  "catalog": [
    {
      "img_href": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179361.jpg",
      "name": "ADITI HAND BLOCKED PRINT",
      "price": 16
    },
    {
      "img_href": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179330.jpg",
      "name": "TORBAY HAND BLOCKED PRINT",
      "price": 17
    },
    {
      "img_href": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179362.jpg",
      "name": "ADITI HAND BLOCKED PRINT",
      "price": 18
    }
  ],
  "datetime": 161878993658
  "catalog_id": 1
}
```

I would like to flatten it and reconstruct as below

```
[
  {
    "datetime": 161878993658,
    "url": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179361.jpg"
  },
  {
    "datetime": 161878993658,
    "url": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179330.jpg"
  },
  {
    "datetime": 161878993658,
    "url": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179362.jpg"
  },
]
```

Comment: Just to make sure: This column is part of a table, is of type variant, and contains objects like the one above? How does the table look?

Comment: thats correct and table has only column of type variant like above

Comment: I have just added "catalog_id" @FelipeHoffa

Comment: Probably a JS-UDF will be the quickest way to solve this one https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/udf-js.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do this.  You won't need the CTE, so delete it and replace uses of `tbl` with the name of your table and uses of `json` with your variant column.

```sql
/*delete this line*/ with tbl as (select parse_json($1) json from values('{"catalog":[{"img_href":"https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179361.jpg","name":"ADITI HAND BLOCKED PRINT","price":16},{"img_href":"https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179330.jpg","name":"TORBAY HAND BLOCKED PRINT","price":17},{"img_href":"https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179362.jpg","name":"ADITI HAND BLOCKED PRINT","price":18}],"datetime":161878993658,"catalog_id":1}'))

select array_agg(new_col) reconstructed
from (
  /* replace json and tbl */ select object_construct('datetime', json:datetime, 'url', obj.value:img_href) new_col, json:catalog_id catalog_id
  from tbl, lateral flatten(json:catalog) obj
) group by catalog_id;
```

It outputs

```
[
  {
    "datetime": 161878993658,
    "url": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179361.jpg"
  },
  {
    "datetime": 161878993658,
    "url": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179330.jpg"
  },
  {
    "datetime": 161878993658,
    "url": "https://schumacher-webassets.s3.amazonaws.com/Web%20Catalog-600/179362.jpg"
  }
]
```